# can't connect to the SQL database

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I created a database in SQL Server Management Studio and I called it SalonDatabase. I tried to connect to the database in VS C#. For this I created two connectionString and only one of them work so I would like to know why.

This one works:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SalonDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

However, the following does not work even though I know for a fact that the file is located in that directory

```
string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                                 Initial Catalog=C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SALONDATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

The error I'm getting is :

> Cannot open database "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SALONDATABASE.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'USER-PC\USER'

Now I logged in as administrator in my computer. I also read about the user instances in SQL server but I don't see that is the reason why the second connection fails.

Comment: A catalog is not a file in that context

Comment: I tried attachdbfilename too but I get the same error

Comment: [User Instances are deprecated.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The database is created using `SQL Server Management Studio` so do not use AttachDBFileName. You may use Server Explorer (from View Menu) tool of Visual Studio to obtain the connection string.

Add connection From Server-Explorer + Right mouse click on Data Connections + Add Connection + Select Microsoft Sql Server Data Source (change).

After adding connection, right mouse click to select/open properties windows.

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SalonDatabase;Integrated Security=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your connection to 'attach' your mdf. Given that your .mdf path has spaces, be sure to enclose it in single quotes.

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;
AttachDbFilename='C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SALONDATABASE.MDF';
Database=dbname; 
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: that's why I used @ before the path.

Comment: No, you used @ because you're using a string literal, allowing multilined layouts. You'll still have problems with a path with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`Initial Catalog` is used to set the Default Database name when we Connect to a Server.
when you are passing the complete path of the database file the connection String makes a search for a database with name `C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SALONDATABASE.MDF`
which actually does not exists therefore it fails.
you can use the initial approach and if you want to use full path then `AttachDbFilename` can be used as suggested by P.Campbell

Answer (score 0):

By default, when working with SQL Server (any edition), the server part handles all the file-related chores for you. You just create a new database (or attach an existing one) and give it a logical **database name** and then you refer to that database solely via this database name - you don't care (and don't need to) about the actual files that make up your database.

That's why your first connection string works - you're telling SQL Server (Express) that you want to work with a database called `SalonDatabase` and SQL Server knows which files this concerns.

Microsoft introduced this notion of being able to "dynamically" create a user-instance of SQL Server Express and attaching a **physical .MDF file** (instead of referring to a database by logical name) as a developer tool to make things easier - but quite frankly, in my opinion, it's a rather messy concept and has lots of drawbacks.

In this scenario, you basically tell SQL Server in your connection string (using `AttachDbFileName=salondatabase.mdf` and with `User Instance=True`) that it should start a separate instance of SQL Server Express for your user context, and automagically attach that physical MDF file specified as its database, and provide you access to that.

As mentioned by another comment, it's a deprecated feature - SQL Server 2012 will bring a new, hopefully slicker concept of local databases. So in my opinion, you should try to avoid using this feature - it's more trouble than anything else.